# Backbone.Syphon - always return empty object

Tags: jquery, forms, backbone.js

I am using `Backbone.Syphon` plugin in my Backbone.Marionette app. when i click on the submit button the form, I am always getting empty object({}).. I don't know the reason for that,

any one help me to find the issue pelase?

here is my view.js

```
define([
    'jQuery','underscore',
    'backbone','marionette',
    'text!./templates/loginView.html'],
    function($,_,Backbone,Marionette,template){
        "use strict";

        var LoginView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

            className:'col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4',

            template:_.template(template),

            events:{
                "submit form" : "loginSubmit"
            },

            loginSubmit:function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(e.target);
                console.log(data); //always return as empty object.
            }

        });

        return LoginView;
    }
);
```

here is my form:

```
<form action="#" id="loginForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <legend>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="userName">UserName</label>
            <input type="text" value="" id="userName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Username">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="text" id="password" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Password">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" id="login">
        </fieldset>
    </legend>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am updated my form html adding `name` to the elements. It works fine.

here is the updated html:

```
<form action="#" id="loginForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <legend>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="userName">UserName</label>
            <input type="text" value="" id="userName" name="userName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Username">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="text" id="password" value="" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Password">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" id="login">
        </fieldset>
    </legend>
</form>
```